# "Unsupported HTTP method" error response while using PUT method to update employee record through REST Webservices in NetSuite

Tags: rest, web-services, postman, netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

We are using REST WebServices and I am testing to update an employee record's email address via POSTMAN.

HTTP method: `PUT`

Endpoint: `https://<accountid>.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/employee`

JSON body:

```
{
    "email": "rest@xyz123.com"
}
```

Once this is send, system gives the error of UNSUPPORTED HTTP METHOD. below is the error responce:

```
{
    "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.6",
    "title": "Method Not Allowed",
    "status": 405,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "Unsupported HTTP method for the requested resource.",
            "o:errorCode": "INVALID_METHOD"
        }
    ]
}
```

Although I'm able to update the employee record through `PATCH` method,(and I tried using `PUT` in RESTlets and it works there), I need to know if the PUT method is not supported in NetSuite REST Webservices or I m doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint needs to include the employee ID to identify the record you want to modify.  Without this, only `GET` (returns a list) or `POST` (creates new record) are valid.

GET /employee (Get list of records.)

POST /employee  (Insert record.)

**PUT /employee/{id} (Insert or update record.)**

More information in the [NetSuite REST API Browser documentation](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2023.2/index.html#tag-employee)

Comment: i did try doing the same thing, but received the same error. If i use PATCH method, i get no error.

Comment: Documentation says ID for PUT is an external ID for upsert. I use external ID for this and I get error as well. Methods PATCH, GET and DELETE require internal ID. However, I can't solve it despite noticing this difference between them.

Comment: Good point.  Your answer is helpful too +1.  The OP had no id in the URL at all, so that's the point I was making.

Answer (score 1):

All troubles come from NetSuite's document [NetSuite REST API Browser: Record API v1](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2023.2/index.html) because it gives you example as follows:

```
PUT /employee/{id} (Insert or update record)
```

So firstly you need to notice that `id` is an external ID for upsert (not internal like for others), secondly you need to know how to use external ID, because the document [Using the Upsert Operation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_156335203191.html#Using-the-Upsert-Operation) is more exact:

```
PUT /employee/eid:{externalId}
```

So probably all is about missing prefix `eid` in request path. It works also for GET requests:

```
GET /employee/eid:{externalId}
```